# How to show $f(x,y) \leq \theta f(x,y) + (1-\theta)f(x,y)$ for $\theta \in [0,1]$?

Tags: calculus, functions, inequality, convex-optimization

Let $\theta \in [0, 1]$. Let $f(x,y)$ be a function. Is there a way I could prove that $f(x,y) \leq \theta f(x,y) + (1-\theta)f(x,y)$?

I have tried to start with $f(x,y) = 2f(x,y) - f(x,y)$ or similar simple equalities but I only find dead ends.

I could not find any counter examples.

Comment: $\theta f(x,y)+(1-\theta)f(x,y)=f(x,y)$...so your question is pretty simple...

Answer (score 2):

$\theta f(x,y)+(1-\theta)f(x,y) = (1-\theta+\theta)f(x,y) = f(x,y)$

This is trivial if I understood your question correct.

Comment: Ha. I feel silly now. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Well this can happen, I bet everyone of this community has come to a 'problem' like this more than once=)